# How to alias static methods in SQL Server to equivalents in an H2 in-memory database

Tags: java, sql-server, integration-testing, h2

I am working on adding automated integration tests to an application that runs against SQL Server in production. The application uses GIS functions in SQL Server and I am trying to build out equivalent versions in the in-memory H2 database (where I am using http://www.h2gis.org/ for the extra tooling for GIS calculations).

The SQL Server queries I am trying to validate use relatively simple GIS functions, like the example below.

```
SELECT
  LOCATION_ID,
  FROMLOCATION.FROMLOC.STDistance(TOLOCATION.TOLOC) * 0.000621371 AS MILES 
FROM
  dbo.MYTABLE1
```

Another example:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MYTABLE1 (LOCATION)
VALUES (geography::POINT(:latitude, :longitude, 4326));
```

In all cases, the H2-provided functions differ in name from the SQL Server ones and I have been trying to create aliases that would work (http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_alias). The problem I am running into is that H2 is not allowing me to create aliases that include the `::` operator from T-SQL. I get the following error when I create such aliases:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of resource class path resource [sql/Aliases.sql]: create alias geography::Point for "com.example.DbFunctions.createWkt"; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE ALIAS GEOGRAPHY::[*]POINT FOR ""com.example.DbFunctions.createWkt"" "; expected "., DETERMINISTIC, NOBUFFER, AS, FOR"; SQL statement:
create alias geography::Point for "com.example.DbFunctions.createWkt" [
```

If I change the alias to something generic (like `apoint` rather than `geography::Point`), the test works.

Is there any way to work around this and build wrapper functions? My current approach is to do text replaces to translate the GIS calls from the SQL Server dialect to the H2 dialect, but I would like to avoid this as it reduces the value of the tests I am trying to write.

Comment: Are you talking about cast operation ? What is the original SQL query you are trying to emulate ?

Comment: @nicolas-f I added some details to the question itself.

Comment: I'm sorry but H2GIS does not support geography. It means that distance function over WGS84 will never give you the expected result.

Comment: In H2 `::` is a reserved operator for cast operation. (convert one type to another)